# Application entry point file not found. nativescript

Tags: android, angularjs, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I create Angular 2 nativescript project and after adding android platform, i run the project in a connected nexus 6p with android version 7.1.1 and when app deployed to the device i got this error:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Application entry point file not found. Please specify the file in package.json otherwise make sure the file index.js or bootstrap.js exists.\nIf using typescript make sure your entry point file is transpiled to javascript.
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5406)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Application entry point file not found. Please specify the file in package.json otherwise make sure the file index.js or bootstrap.js exists.\nIf using typescript make sure your entry point file is transpiled to javascript.
 at com.tns.Module.bootstrapApp(Module.java:337)
 at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:508)
 at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:17)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5403)
 ... 8 more
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./", relative to: app//
 at com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:159)
 at com.tns.Module.bootstrapApp(Module.java:335)
 ... 12 more
```

any idea how can i solve this error?

**Update:**

i create the project with `tns create name --ng` and i just run it with `tns run android` command.
the `package.js` file:

```
{
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "readme": "NativeScript Application",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "org.nativescript.Bazim",
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "2.4.1"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
        "nativescript-angular": "1.2.0",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "^0.2.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "tns-core-modules": "2.4.3",
        "typescript": "~2.0.10",

    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-traverse": "6.21.0",
        "babel-types": "6.21.0",
        "babylon": "6.14.1",
        "lazy": "1.0.11",
        "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
        "typescript": "~2.0.10",
        "zone.js": "~0.6.21"
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide some more info about the problem? It would help if you post some code and the project `package.json` file?

Comment: @NikolayTsonev i updated the question.

Comment: You could try to remove `node_modules`, `platforms` and `hooks` folders and to rebuild the app. Could you also give us info about CLI version - `tns --version` and `node --version`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was from node version, i updated the node and the problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

The `package.json` file you posted is the wrong one.

There should be another one inside the `app` folder.
It should look something likes this :

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "main": "app.js", //THIS IT THE ENTRYPOINT
  "version": "X.X.X",
  "author": {
    "name": "Name",
    "email": "some@email.com"
  },
  "description": "some desc!",
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/yourrepo"
  }
}
```

Verify that the entry point file exists (it has to be a `.js` file and not a a typescript file) and you should be good to go.

Comment: the entrypoint is in typescript format, how should i make `.js` file?

Comment: but do you see the js file or is it still not being compiled ?

Comment: Ok then try to `tns remove typescript` and `tns install typescript` and try to build again.  Then see if js files have been produced

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130947/discussion-between-aaron-ullal-and-pourya8086).

Comment: Thanks dude. Saved me hours of time I would have spent trying to track this down. I cherry picked some files to copy over from my app I generated with the NativeScript CLI to a new project and left out app/package.json because I thought it was some extra crap that wasn't needed.

Comment: What `.js` file are we talking about here ? And is it supposed to be specifed somewhere in a json file ?

Answer (score 0):

the entry point is defined in angular.json

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/output",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
```

but error like this can happen if we have any compile errors, I had it with tests and sub application, I excluded it in tsconfig and now it works

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to my NativeScript CLI version. Updated the version and the issue was solved. Just for reference I was at angular-cli 7.3.6 and NativeScript-cli 5.4.0 (got the issue) updated to NativeScript-cli 5.4.2 to solve the issue. Anyone facing the similar issue, try updating your NativeScript CLI version.